# Make a custom layout article view

Tags: php, layout, joomla, article

I am making a site for a car company. Whenever I add an article there are two options: Blog and Category. I would like something like a category with a image preview and instead of the date created to show something like price, or brand.

Is there any simple way to do it? Or any extension already made?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you looked into? Which components have you tried? Which version of Joomla?

Comment: It's joomla 2.5 .I tried to use mini frontpage but I didn't see any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this extension. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/8061. With k2 you can add custom fields for articles. After, you can adjust template for displaying additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something specific for cars, then I would recommend RD Autos. They have a free version that does most everything you would need as well as a pro version that had additional features.

https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/vehicles/5458